# Problem (or maybe bug) with the SmoothHistogram3D command?

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, histograms, logarithmic-scale

I have a data set in form of {x,y} (I add part of my data set), and I need to calculate the 3D histogram for it, also I need to get -LOG from probability (Z axes). I wrote this code for it.

```
Energy2 =
SmoothHistogram3D[togather,
ScalingFunctions -> {"None", "None", -Log[#] &}, ImageSize -> Full,
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
AxesLabel -> {"Radius Of Gyration(\[Angstrom])",
"Number of Native Contacts", "Energy"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

and I will get this error message, "`Message text not found -- ({None,None,-Log[#1]&})`", what is wrong with my code?

```
{{16.3009, 9345}, {16.2118, 9470}, {15.8156, 9439}, {15.9585, 9542},
{15.6112, 9414}, {15.7221, 9370}, {15.509, 9450}, {15.6993, 9398},
{16.4999, 9487}, {16.3784, 9453}, {16.9554, 9684}, {16.9463, 9506},
{16.9786, 9549}, {17.2081, 9461}, {17.4898, 9398}, {17.1521, 9674},
{17.92, 8789}, {18.0992, 8740}, {18.1392, 8549}, {18.5486, 8501},
{18.9874, 8727}, {18.9643, 8710}, {18.5903, 8681}, {18.6687, 8687},
{17.8913, 8784}, {18.1319, 8517}, {18.6675, 8632}, {18.9163, 8868},
{18.2755, 8446}, {18.2921, 8541}, {18.629, 8426}, {18.876, 8359}}
```

Comment: You should share a minimal example of your code that shows the problem in order for people to be able to help you.

Comment: I tried to add my code by I got error message!!!

Comment: ROGF = Import["RoGf-B4MS.dat", "Table"];
NCF = Import["nativenumcontacts-folded.dat", "Table"];
ROGF = Map[#[[2]] &, ROGF];
NCF = Map[#[[2]] + #[[3]] &, NCF];
togather = Table[{ROGF[[i]], NCF[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[ROGF]}];
Energy2 = 
 SmoothHistogram3D[togather, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, -Log[#] &}, ImageSize -> Full, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Radius Of Gyration(\[Angstrom])", 
    "Number of Native Contacts", "Energy"}, PlotRange -> All] "code with smoothHistogram3D"

Comment: part of data set in format {x(dat1),y(dat2)}:{{16.3009, 9345}, {16.2118, 9470}, {15.8156, 9439}, {15.9585,  9542}, {16.2253, 9563}, {16.284, 9411}, {15.6112, 9414}, {15.7221, 
  9370}, {15.509, 9450}, {15.6993, 9398}, {15.961, 9431}, {16.6001, 
  9464}, {16.3766, 9372}, {16.4999, 9487}, {16.3784, 9453}, {16.9554, 
  9684}, {16.9463, 9506}, {17.2453, 9355}, {17.0854, 9710}, {16.9786, 
  9549}, {17.2081, 9461}, {17.4898, 9398}, {17.1521, 9674}, {17.8233, 
  9266}, {17.726, 9389}, {17.7837, 9575}, {17.5088, 9566}, {17.8232, 
  9569}, {18.4418, 9443}, {17.8446, 9602}}

Comment: What is `togather`? The data provided below?

Comment: yes, it is. I have to the different set of the data set(ROG&NCF) and I made a set of data in form of {x,y} and called together.

Comment: The documentation states that the option is `None` and not `"None"`.

Comment: I tried that too, but I got the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's your version of Mathematica.  Using 10.4.1 (Windows 7) the following works:

```
togather = {{16.3009, 9345}, {16.2118, 9470}, {15.8156, 
    9439}, {15.9585, 9542}, {15.6112, 9414}, {15.7221, 9370}, {15.509,
     9450}, {15.6993, 9398}, {16.4999, 9487}, {16.3784, 
    9453}, {16.9554, 9684}, {16.9463, 9506}, {16.9786, 
    9549}, {17.2081, 9461}, {17.4898, 9398}, {17.1521, 9674}, {17.92, 
    8789}, {18.0992, 8740}, {18.1392, 8549}, {18.5486, 
    8501}, {18.9874, 8727}, {18.9643, 8710}, {18.5903, 
    8681}, {18.6687, 8687}, {17.8913, 8784}, {18.1319, 
    8517}, {18.6675, 8632}, {18.9163, 8868}, {18.2755, 
    8446}, {18.2921, 8541}, {18.629, 8426}, {18.876, 8359}};
Energy2 = 
 SmoothHistogram3D[togather, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, -Log[#] &}, ImageSize -> Full, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Radius Of Gyration(Å)", 
    "Number of Native Contacts", "Energy"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: 3D smooth histogram]

What version and platform are you using?

(And on a more semantics note:  you are getting the log of the estimated probability density and not the log of the probability.)

**Update**

The above is simply an attempt to remove the errors you're seeing.  But if you really need a set of `-Log[density]` values, then there are more direct ways to do so.  Here is a way that gets you the density values on a grid of x,y values:

```
(* Estimate a bivariate probability density *)
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[togather];

(* Make a 100x100 table of estimates of density *)
n = 100;
density = 
  Table[{13 + (22 - 13) i/n, 7000 + (11000 - 7000) j/n, 
   PDF[skd, {13 + (22 - 13) i/n, 7000 + (11000 - 7000) j/n}]}, 
  {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];

(* Plot the results *)
ListPointPlot3D[density, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: 3D density]

You'll need to be wary of density values of zero or very close to zero if you really need `-Log[density]`.

Comment: `ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, -Log[#] &}` does not work for me; I have Mathematica 12.0